# how to apply active class using ng-class for list elements(mutli-select)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a scenario,that I have static list elements,where I need to add active class using ng-class,when I click on list element,the active class would be added.

Here is my code:

```
vm.idArry = [];
vm.selectedFunc = function (item) {
    item.selected = !item.selected;
    if(vm.idArry.indexOf(item) == -1){
        vm.idArry.push(item);

    }
    else {
        var index =  vm.idArry.indexOf(item);
         vm.idArry.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Html:

```
<ul>
            <li id="one"><a ng-class="{'active':item.selected}" ng-click="selectedrFunc(1)" ></a></li>
            <li id="two"><a ng-class="{'active':item.selected}" ng-click="selectedFunc(2)" ></a></li>
            <li id="three"><a ng-class="{'active':item.selected}" ng-click="selectedFunc(3)"></a></li>
            <li id="four"><a ng-class="{'active':item.selected}" ng-click="selectedFunc(4)" ></a></li>
            <li id="five"><a ng-class="{'active':item.selected}" ng-click="selectedFunc(5)"></a></li>
            <li id="six"><a ng-class="{'active':item.selected}" ng-click="selectedFunc(6)" ></a></li>
```

for the above code,I have to get append active class when I click on list elements(i.e; multiple list must be added active class when I clicked on multiple list elements).

Thanks in advance.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove usage of item.selected and use following code:

```
<li id="one"><a ng-class="{'active': vm.idArry.indexOf(1) != -1}" ng-click="selectedFunc(1)" >A</a></li>
```

This checks for item existence in `vm.idArray`; Also remove `item.selected` on `vm.selectedFunc`

So your vm.selectedFunc should look like this:

```
vm.selectedFunc = function (item) {
    if(vm.idArry.indexOf(item) == -1){
        vm.idArry.push(item);

    }
    else {
        var index =  vm.idArry.indexOf(item);
         vm.idArry.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```